# Change timestamp without effect date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am using SSMS and I have a table with date/time stored in a column. What i need to do is change the time but leave the date.

Example: 2020-07-28 00:00:00. I need to change the timestamp 00:00:00 to 23:59:00 without changing the date for the whole column.

```
CPRDate -- Column Header
2020-07-28 00:00:00
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add them together -- as `datetime`s:

```
select cprdate + convert(datetime, convert(time, '23:59:00'))
```

This construct is clearly [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/arithmetic-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and supported by SQL Server:

> The plus (+) and minus (-) operators can also be used to run arithmetic operations on `datetime` and `smalldatetime` values.

You can use the same construct in an `update` if you want to change the stored value.

If `cprdate` is a `date`, you need to convert it to a `datetime` for this to work.

Comment: One should not be encouraging the bad habit of applying mathematical operators to non-arithmetic datatypes. Yes it works - until datetime2 becomes involved. But it's a bad habit to develop.

Comment: @Smor . . . This is clearly documented:  "The plus (+) and minus (-) operators can also be used to run arithmetic operations on datetime and smalldatetime values."    (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/arithmetic-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  You should really communicate your issues to Microsoft.

Comment: The problem with that is not all the times are 00:00:00 that was my mistake in the original post. the timestamp varies the further you go in the column so while that would work in the example it wouldn't fix my over all problem

Comment: @Chatleli . . . Then you should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  This question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could add subtract one minute and add a day to achieve this, i.e.

`update MYTABLE SET CPRDate = DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(minute, -1, CPRDATE));`

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/71ecc/1)  to show it working.